# correct usage of carets inside negative lookahead expression in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match any word that is not completely composed of capitals or lowercase letters, and I have the following regex written:

```
if ($line =~ /(?!^[A-Z][A-Z]+(\s*)$)(?!^[a-z][a-z]+(\s*)$)/) {
    print $line;
}
```

The expression below should match words with all capital letters

```
(?!^[A-Z][A-Z]+(\s*)$)
```

and this should match words with all lowercase letters

```
(?!^[a-z][a-z]+(\s*)$)
```

I combine both and try to match this with the following words, ASDSFSDF, asdfasdfasdf, and asdasdfFFFdsfs. I notice that it is matching everything. only when i move the caret outside the brackets as in:

```
^(?![A-Z][A-Z]+(\s*)$)^(?![a-z][a-z]+(\s*)$)/)
```

do i see that its only maching the asdasdfFFFdsfs. can someone explain to me why i need to move the operator outside of the negative lookahead expression? i am new to regexp and i am confused.

Thanks.

Comment: The part `[A-Z][A-Z]+` is equivalent to `[A-Z]{2,}`, meaning it will match at least two or more upper case letters. Perhaps this is what you meant to do, in which case the latter regex is more readable, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fell in a trap of multiple negations and anchoring, and you resulting regex didn't quite do what you want. Let's assume we only have the simplified regex `/(?!^[A-Z]$)/` and the string `"1"`.

At the first position (before the `1`), the assertion is tested. The `^` matches here, but `[A-Z]` does not. Therefore, `^[A-Z]` *fails*. As the lookahead is *negative*, the whole pattern succeeds.

Now let's assume we have the string `"A"`. At the first position, the assertion is tested. The pattern `^[A-Z]$` matches here. Because it is a negative lookahead, the assertion fails.

Then, the second position is tested (after the `A`). The assertion is tested, but `^` doesn't match here – thus the negative assertion makes the pattern succeed!

Therefore, your regex doesn't match the patterns you wanted. You can suppress this behaviour by anchoring outside the assertion:

```
/^(?![A-Z]$)/
```

in this case. Note that in your case, the easiest solution is to write a regex that matches all inputs you *don't* want, and the negating that result:

```
print $line unless $line =~ /^(?:[A-Z]{2,}|[a-z]{2,})\s*$/;
```

(Edit: actually TLP's 2nd solution is even simpler, and likely more efficient)

Comment: I appreciate the detailed explanation. This has cleared things up for me quite a lot. I thought the expression ^[a-z][a-z]+(\s*)$ inside would match words that began with a lowercase letter, followed by lowercase letters, and ended with a space. Is that the right way to think about it? I didnt realize that inside the (?!) bracket it would always be looking for the beginning of a word, which caused my expressions to succeed.

Comment: @mlikj2006 The `^` operator only ever matches at the beginning of a line. It has nothing to do with word boundaries (`\b`). A negative lookahead asserts that the enclosed pattern cannot match (at the current position). If a part of a regex cannot match at the current position, it tries at another position. Anchors like `^` can be used to fix part of the patterns, which limits this behaviour. If you are unsure about a regex feature, and the docs don't help, then reducing the regex and testing it with various inputs can help your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

How about just checking the string for the upper and lower case characters?

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])
```

As you see, this will not match strings consisting of only one case, because both lookaheads must match.

Of course, this is just a complicated way of performing two regex matches and combining the result:

```
if ($line =~ /[A-Z]/ and $line =~ /[a-z]/)
```

Comment: wow. didnt realize how absurd mine looked till i saw this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This would match mixed cases for the whole word:

```
^[[:alpha:]]*([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]|[[:lower:]][[:upper:]])[[:alpha:]]*$
```

A little smaller:

```
^[A-Za-z]*([A-Z][a-z]|[a-z][A-Z])[A-Za-z]*$
```

Comment: using ^[a-zA-Z]+$ matches everything. Is there a way to match only asdasdfFFFdsfs

Comment: @mlikj2006 What is the criterion for that string to be matched and not some other?